# ssh fails when is being called within windows service

Tags: windows-services, ssh

I'm calling `cmd` file that calls `ssh` to intercommunicate with Linux machine. I use .NET `Process` class to accomplish this. But when being called within Windows Service call fails with following error:

```
C:\test>ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i private_linux_key user@host "ls" 
      0 [main] ssh 9496 fhandler_base::dup: dup(some disk file) failed, handle 0, Win32 error 6
dup() in/out/err failed
```

Everything works when I start application as Console application.

What may be possible reason of this failure and how to fix this?

**EDIT** All Windows service has to do - somehow kill predefined daemon on Linux machine

Thanks

**EDIT**

Similar problem described there: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t714254-executing-commands-from-windows-service.html

Comment: We've got the same issue. We wrote a program to automatically create DOS batch files and to execute them. The program takes care of standard in, out and error. More specific, it creates a batch file which calls sh.exe (part of msysgit) to execute BASH shell scripts. In the shell script we use the ssh command, which returns a very similar error message as yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this post will save someones time to struggle similar problem. I've finally found solution that works for me. It is `ssh -n` key

So instead of

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i private_linux_key user@host "ls"
```

I've used

```
ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i private_linux_key user@host "ls"
```

It still looks like a magic, but it works!

Comment: It works for our program which handles itself standard input, output and error .

Comment: The flag -T is handy to surpress an error message of ssh that it can't allocate a pseudo terminal. So it may become: ssh -n -T

Comment: Exactly, it works!.. but in my case I could not change the parameters easily. Need to understand the difference

Answer (score 0):

isn't it a problem of access credentials ?

when running your program as a console applicaiton, you are using the access rights of the currently logged on user. however, a Windows Service executes in a special user account (generally "SYSTEM"), and as such is not granted the same access rights.

Comment: No. I've tried to run service under different accounts including my windows credentials, always same results